# windows xp sp3 bsod - what do numbers in parenthesis mean?

Tags: windows-xp, vmware, bsod

I'm getting a BSOD on my Windows XP SP3 image (running on Workstation 8) all of a sudden. Here is the message:

```
stop: 0x000000D1 (0x00000008, 0x00000002, 0x00000000, 0x8616A7c5)
```

I've tried to debug the D1 error - what do the other values represent?  I'm hoping they can point me to a solution to my problem.  Any ideas what the last 4 numbers represent?

Comment: This is always a driver bug.  You can only debug it if you have the source for the driver.  I doubt you have it, you would know what the numbers mean.  Contact the owner or author of the driver for an update.

Comment: 0xD1 is a very common error, here is the description of its meaning and parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560244(v=vs.85).aspx. Like @HansPassant has mentioned, you can't do much without driver source code.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the computer is [correctly configured](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130536) to save a crash dump file. The 1-st parametr - memory referenced `0x00000008` bad address in both user and kernel mode at any IRQL. The 4-th parametr - address that referenced memory `0x8616A7c5`. Instruction in a module that is loaded at this address causes an error.

Answer (score 0):

download win-debugger from Microsoft and then open the crash dump files. you could also see the calling stack and know which process cause the BSOD.

Comment: that's what I tried to do.  Unfortunately I'm fighting the fact that I cannot get my system to dump a log file.  I've tried the steps below to get a dump with no luck.  I've tried small mem dumps, kernel and everything.  When I reboot in Safe mode after the BSOD, the file is not there.  Guess there's no way to figure out what the issue is with just the BSOD error codes

1. Start-Run-sysdm.cpl.
2. On the Advanced tab, in the Startup and Recovery section, click Settings.
3. In the Write debugging information list, click Kernel memory dump, and then click OK